# Is there a word for "stripped of ones essential weirdness"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word like "emasculated" or "neutered" except here it would mean "stripped of one's essential weirdness".

You could use it in a sentence like:

> He was *[stripped of his essential weirdness]* so he just cried through his pants like a broken sea-monkey.

Comment: I don't think your sentence *precisely* conveys that loss of essential weirdness.

Comment: The character had his "essential weirdness" stripped, but the writer did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Abstracted** could work, though there is no reference to the nature of what is being taken away or withdrawn.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abstraction

*abstraction*
the act of obtaining or removing something from a source

As in, "hydrogen atoms are abstracted from organic compounds during halogenation reactions."

Comment: Yes and no.  As you mention it doesn't say what is being stripped.  Likewise the word "stripped" or "removed" could be used in much the same regard.  I'll probably end up eventually accepting and upvoting this as it is probably as close as one gets.

Comment: I didn't think of this before, but the word could imply a transformation to a less unique state (but that's only if you want to combine definitions, which is probably a no-no?)

Answer (score 2):

You might use an antonym of *weird* and make it a verb, such as *normalized* or *standardized*. 
Or, say if his weirdness is an aspect of being an urban city dweller, he may have been *suburbanized*.
And you can also say he was *de-weirded* or *unweirded*.
I don't think there is a word to describe what you want, so you will likely have to craft one from parts of others.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not.  Probably because an essential weirdness is more likely to be an intrinsic ( i.e. non-strippable) one rather than one that is merely "important."

Answer (score -1):

***Taken aback*** doesn't exactly fit your parameters (I'm not sure what might), but it somewhat fits the context of your sentence.

*taken aback*

confused or surprised by something unexpected Company executives have been taken aback by the criticism. I asked him directly if he was looking for someone with my skills, and I think he was kind of taken aback.
Etymology: based on the literal meaning of aback (backward), which is not used in modern English http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/taken+aback